# How to remove watermark from TIFFs to improve OCR

Tags: imagemagick, watermark, gimp

I have a bunch of uncompressed bitonal TIF document images. All of them have a watermark in the middle. When I run them through OCR, the text that overlaps with the watermark does not get recognized. I am trying to see if I can apply some type of cleanup to remove those watermarks to be able to recognize the missing text.

Again, the images are black and white, but when you look at the watermark it appears grey since it has a pattern of black and white pixels that makes the letters in the watermark less "dense" than regular text. At the same time, the watermark letters are very big, much bigger than the regular text.

An example of a somewhat similar image is [this](http://blogs.zoho.com/image/13000000306068/zoho-writer-watermark-3.png) (except this one is color and the watermark characters in my case are a lot thicker and bigger; my watermarks are also a lot shorter: only 3 to 4 letters long)

It seems that there might be some sort of clean up filter that would be similar to removing large black borders from an image except borders are ually "denser" than a watermark so they appear "more black".

I have 3 tools at my disposal: GIMP, ImageMagick and IrfanView. Can you recommend any specific features of any subset of these tools that might help me?

Comment: Is the watermark a notation (e.g. 'confidential', 'draft' etc) or is it specifically intended to confuse OCR ('Evaluation copy' etc)?

Comment: OK, coolio. If you turn up the brightness and the contrast (either with Gimp or IM) then grey artifacts may fall away, with black surviving.

Comment: Thanks, but I think both brightness and contrast operate on grayscale or color images. I need to keep the image black and white. That is, I can clean up in several steps and turn the image to grayscale at some point but the final result should be b/w. I played with brightness and contrast a bit and don't think they will help. At least not by themselves.

Comment: Convert to greyscale, do the adjustments, convert back to monochrome? `:)` I am quite sure this will work in the general case, though YMWV as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with contrast etc did not help, but I found a different way. As stated above, the regular text is a lot "denser" than the watermark text meaning that a regular black pixel has more surrounding black pixels than a watermark black pixel. So I devised a simple window-based filtering and thresholding algorithm.

Here's how I did it in Matlab, using a 5X5 window:

```
im=imread('imageWithWmark.tif');
imInv = ~im;
nr=size(imInv,1);
nc=size(imInv,2);

d = 2;  % for 5X5 window
counts = zeros(nr,nc);
for rr = d+1 : nr-d-1
for cc = d+1 : nc-d-1
    counts(rr,cc) = nnz(imInv(rr-d:rr+d,cc-d:cc+d));
end
end

thresh=10;  % 10 out of 25 -- the larger the thresh the thinner the resulting letters are
imThresh = (counts>=thresh) & imInv;
imwrite(~imThresh,sprintf('Thresh_%d.tif',thresh),'Compression','none','Resolution',300);
```

Of course, the size of the window, the threshold and other parameters depend on the parameters of the regular text on the page (letter bigger/smaller, thicker/thinner etc) but even this initial version worked pretty well